# ionic3/angular5: Safari API calls not sending sessionid cookie withCredentials: true

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cookies, safari, mobile-safari

I’ve been struggling for some time with this and I’m wondering if anyone here can help.

I have an ionic 3/angular 5 app that is accessing an external API. Upon login, the server is sending a session id that I’m using to authenticate all subsequent data calls. Chrome and Android are working fine. Safari and iOS are not.

The login code in my service is straightforward:

```
public login(credentials): Observable<Object> {
    let httpParams = this.httpParams;
    for (let key in credentials){ httpParams = httpParams.set(key, credentials[key])};
    return this.httpClient.post(this.url + this.loginEndpoint, httpParams, { withCredentials: true });
}
```

and when it’s called:

```
this.authServiceProvider.login({username: this.username, password: this.password}).subscribe(data => {
    <display logged in page>
});
```

But as I make another call to the dataProvider, Safari is instantiating a new session on the server, ie. not sending the session id cookie from the previous request.

CORS is working. Here are the headers my server is sending, including the cookie.

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:8100
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 95
content-type: text/javascript
date: Wed, 21 Mar 2018 15:55:50 GMT
server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
set-cookie: JSESSIONID=BE1997D948436D29A90DA24DC518E29F; Path=/api/; HttpOnly
status: 200
vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
```

and here are the headers that Chrome is sending on the following request:

```
:authority: api.com
:method: POST
:path: /api/login.jsp
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 283
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
cookie: JSESSIONID=BE1997D948436D29A90DA24DC518E29F; _ga=GA1.2.744976386.1521627198; _gid=GA1.2.533597894.1521627198
origin: http://localhost:8100
referer: http://localhost:8100/?ionicplatform=android&http://localhost:8100/ionic-lab
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
```

and here are the headers that Safari is sending for the second request:

```
Referer: http://localhost:8100/?ionicplatform=android&http://localhost:8100/ionic-lab
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Origin: http://localhost:8100
Host: api.com
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 283
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0.2 Safari/604.4.7
```

If I go into Safari’s preferences and uncheck Security > Website tracking > Prevent cross-site tracking, everything works as expected. Safari sends the cookie.

```
Referer: http://localhost:8100/?ionicplatform=android&http://localhost:8100/ionic-lab
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Origin: http://localhost:8100
Host: api.com
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0.2 Safari/604.4.7
Cookie: JSESSIONID=32D79DD5171A6B82783252CE22E55083
Content-Length: 283
```

But obviously this is not a solution for users of the iOS app.

Anyone have any experience with this? I’ve found a lot of people with similar issues over the years but most of the solutions haven’t worked for me

Any help is most appreciated! And let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [CORDOVA PLUGIN](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-http)

This should resolve the issue